# Telerik RadDatePicker problem in ClientIDMode="Static"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik-raddatepicker

```js
var StartDate = $('#dtStartDate').val();
var EndDate = $('#dtEndDate').val();
alert(StartDate);
alert(EndDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Start Date</td>
    <td>
      <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dtStartDate" CssClass="Telepicker" runat="server" ZIndex="100000" ClientIDMode="Static" DateInput-EmptyMessage="dd/mm/yyyy" Culture="English (United States)">
        <DateInput ID="DateInput1" DateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" runat="server"></DateInput>
        <Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" EnableKeyboardNavigation="true" ShowRowHeaders="False" MonthLayout="Layout_7columns_x_6rows" DayNameFormat="FirstLetter" ShowOtherMonthsDays="false">
          <SpecialDays>
            <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" ItemStyle-BackColor="Bisque" />
          </SpecialDays>
        </Calendar>
        <DatePopupButton ImageUrl="Calendar.gif" HoverImageUrl="Calendar.gif" />
      </telerik:RadDatePicker>
    </td>
    <td>End Date</td>
    <td>
      <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dtEndDate" CssClass="Telepicker" runat="server" ZIndex="100000" ClientIDMode="Static" DateInput-EmptyMessage="dd/mm/yyyy" Culture="English (United States)">
        <DateInput ID="DateInput2" DateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" runat="server">
        </DateInput>
        <Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server" EnableKeyboardNavigation="true" ShowRowHeaders="False" MonthLayout="Layout_7columns_x_6rows" DayNameFormat="FirstLetter" ShowOtherMonthsDays="false">
          <SpecialDays>
            <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" ItemStyle-BackColor="Bisque" />
          </SpecialDays>
        </Calendar>
        <DatePopupButton ImageUrl="Calendar.gif" HoverImageUrl="Calendar.gif" />
      </telerik:RadDatePicker>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Without using `ClientIDMode="Static"` I can't able to get the date value in `Jquery`.

But when I use `ClientIDMode="Static"` in both `Telerik RadDatePicker` (Start and End) after clicking start date calendar is showing for end date.

I think I'm messed up with both ID's.

Please help me with this. How to get both `Telerik RadDatePicker` (start and End) values in `Jquery`.

Comment: I've never used it, but maybe you need `$('#DateInput1').val();` and DateInput2?? When you select a date, is that where the date is entered?

Answer (score 0):

I found some documentation that looks like below. I think static IDs should work.

```
// get the date picker.
var datePicker = $("#dtStartDate");
// get the selected date from the date picker.
var date = datePicker.get_selectedDate();
```

Or, in one line:

```
var date = $("#dtStartDate").get_selectedDate();
```

I hope that's not from old [docs](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/datetimepicker/client-side-programming/overview).

Comment: The docs have this: `var datetimepicker = $find("<%= RadDateTimePicker1.ClientID %>");`. Also just noticed I was looking at the DateTime picker; hopefully it works the same.